# В SignalR сохранять сообщения в БД (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-core, signalr

Как (работая под ASP.NET Core) в чате красиво все сообщения сохранять в БД и чтобы они уже выводились  другим пользователям. Короче говоря хочу обычный чат реализовать но проблема в том что в стандартно реализованном SignalR идет работа в реальном времени. Как это реализовать или может этот чат вообще по другому делается?

Comment: под кору есть `SignarR-Core`. А в чем проблема? Такое чувство что вы даете кому-то задание ) [Поглядите](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/30.1.php)

Comment: Спасибо большое за отклик @ВиталийШебаниц. Как именно это реализовать? Я все статьи на метаните изучил на эту тему но так и не понял как именно держать сообщения сохраненными. На ютубе англо-язычные инструкции по реализации chat app пересмотрел, там так же не реализуют, из за этого сюда прибежал. Если не трудно хотя бы ткните на конкретную статью.

Comment: Ну, например делаете отдельный сервисный канал. Когда клиент запускается, то по этому каналу запрашивает историю чата за последнее время, выдает ее и начинает работать по реалтайму в основном канале. Но в принципе это можно и на одном канале реализовать, если помечать сообщения: либо это ответы чата, либо ответы на сервисные команды.

Comment: Что значит "как держать сообщения сохраненными"? Забота "живого показа" сообщений - это к `SignalR`(ну или сокетам). Забота сохранения сообщений - это к БД. Смысл прмерно такой: 1) Идете в контроллер, выбираете сообщения "скажем за последнюю неделю" (делите на прочитанные и не прочитанные по признаку в БД) ну и показываете 2) После подключаетесь к сокету-серверу, который будет вещать новые сообщении в разрезе вашего пользователя и если они есть, то показываете.